# centralManager method not being called

Tags: ios, xcode, bluetooth-lowenergy

I am an Android developer, moving over to iOS, so please bear with me regarding the basics of iOS development.

I have the following code:

Here is the `.m` file:

```
#import "BlueToothLEManager.h"
#import "Constants.h"

@implementation BlueToothLEManager

@synthesize mBTCentralManager;


-(void)initializeCBCentralManager{
    NSLog(@"initializing CBCentral Manager"); <--- This is being logged
    mBTCentralManager = [[CBCentralManager alloc] initWithDelegate:self queue:nil];

}

#pragma mark - CBCentralManagerDelegate

// method called whenever you have successfully connected to the BLE peripheral
- (void)centralManager:(CBCentralManager *)central didConnectPeripheral:(CBPeripheral *)peripheral
{
}

// CBCentralManagerDelegate - This is called with the CBPeripheral class as its main input parameter. This contains most of the information there is to know about a BLE peripheral.
- (void)centralManager:(CBCentralManager *)central didDiscoverPeripheral:(CBPeripheral *)peripheral advertisementData:(NSDictionary *)advertisementData RSSI:(NSNumber *)RSSI
{
    NSLog(@"Discovered %@ at %@", peripheral.name, RSSI); 
}

-(void)centralManagerDidUpdateState:(CBCentralManager *)central{
    NSLog(@"Start scan"); <---- This is  NOT being logged. 
    if(central.state != CBCentralManagerStatePoweredOn){
        return;
    }
    if(central.state == CBCentralManagerStatePoweredOn){
        NSLog(@"Scanning for BTLE device"); 
        [mBTCentralManager scanForPeripheralsWithServices:@[[CBUUID UUIDWithString:DEVICE_NAME]] options:@{ CBCentralManagerScanOptionAllowDuplicatesKey : @YES }];
    }
}
@end
```

Here is the `.h` file:

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

@import CoreBluetooth;

@interface BlueToothLEManager : NSObject < CBCentralManagerDelegate, CBPeripheralDelegate>{
    CBCentralManager *mBTCentralManager; 
}

@property (strong, retain) CBCentralManager *mBTCentralManager;

-(void) initializeCBCentralManager;


@end
```

When I call `initializeCBCentralManager` everything appears to work, but for some reason the `centralManagerDidUpdateState` method isn't being called. Can someone tell me what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: What is the declaration of your `mBTCentralManager` property?  Get rid of the `@synthesize` and use `self.mBTCentralManager`. What device are you running this on?

Comment: @Paulw11 this is being tested on a 4S. See edits for property.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should clean up your property definition as your iVar is getting mixed up with your property.  If you declare a property you don't need to declare an iVar.  You also don't need `@synthesize` unless you want a specific name for the backing variable.  If you use the `self.` notation then you can be sure that you are referring to the property and not an iVar.

Your .h file should be -

```
@import CoreBluetooth;

@interface BlueToothLEManager : NSObject < CBCentralManagerDelegate, CBPeripheralDelegate>

@property (strong, retain) CBCentralManager *mBTCentralManager;

-(void) initializeCBCentralManager;

@end
```

Then your .m file will be

```
#import "BlueToothLEManager.h"
#import "Constants.h"

@implementation BlueToothLEManager


-(void)initializeCBCentralManager{
    NSLog(@"initializing CBCentral Manager"); 
    self.mBTCentralManager = [[CBCentralManager alloc] initWithDelegate:self queue:nil];

}

#pragma mark - CBCentralManagerDelegate

// method called whenever you have successfully connected to the BLE peripheral
- (void)centralManager:(CBCentralManager *)central didConnectPeripheral:(CBPeripheral *)peripheral
{
}

// CBCentralManagerDelegate - This is called with the CBPeripheral class as its main input parameter. This contains most of the information there is to know about a BLE peripheral.
- (void)centralManager:(CBCentralManager *)central didDiscoverPeripheral:(CBPeripheral *)peripheral advertisementData:(NSDictionary *)advertisementData RSSI:(NSNumber *)RSSI
{
    NSLog(@"Discovered %@ at %@", peripheral.name, RSSI); 
}

-(void)centralManagerDidUpdateState:(CBCentralManager *)central{
    NSLog(@"Start scan"); 

    if(central.state == CBCentralManagerStatePoweredOn){
        NSLog(@"Scanning for BTLE device"); 
        [central scanForPeripheralsWithServices:@[[CBUUID UUIDWithString:DEVICE_NAME]] options:@{ CBCentralManagerScanOptionAllowDuplicatesKey : @YES }];
    }
}
@end
```

I have tested this and it works

Comment: First off, thank you for your help! I made the changes you suggested but I'm still not able to get the `centralManagerDidUpdateState` method to be called.

Comment: How are you instantiating the `BluetoothLEManager` class and calling `initializeCBCentralManager`?  If you aren't holding a retained reference to this class instance in a property then it will get deallocated.  As I said I have tested the code above and it discovers devices

Comment: I think that might be the problem, again, I'm new to this whole iOS thing, so thank you for your patience. Specifically, I'm calling `[[BlueToothLEManager alloc]initializeCBCentralManager];`. I'm guessing from you last comment that this is why it isn't working.

Comment: That will work - but the result needs to be stored in a variable, and if that variable goes out of scope then the object will be released before the delegate call back can be made - it is like garbage collection in Java.  Where are you storing the result of the alloc\init

Comment: Something like this could be a good candidate for a singleton pattern http://www.galloway.me.uk/tutorials/singleton-classes/

Comment: Thank you very much for your help. I really like the idea of the singleton approach. This VERY helpful. Thank you again.